# @ControllerAdvice not working with proper configuration in spring 4.0.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I am trying to handle and respond to requests with custom error(message) using @ControllerAdvice for Rest API calls.

Trying with configurations and setup and specified in documentations didn't worked well. Here is my code snippet

In RestController a method has following statement

```
if(object==null){   
    throw new CustomGenericException("E_001", "Null error");
}
```

The CustomGenericException class is as below

```
public class CustomGenericException extends RuntimeException {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String errCode;
private String errMsg;

public String getErrCode() {
    return errCode;
}

public void setErrCode(String errCode) {
    this.errCode = errCode;
}

public String getErrMsg() {
    return errMsg;
}

public void setErrMsg(String errMsg) {
    this.errMsg = errMsg;
}

public CustomGenericException(String errCode, String errMsg) {
    this.errCode = errCode;
    this.errMsg = errMsg;
}
}
```

The Custom exception handler class as below

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionController{

    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(CustomGenericException.class)
    public @ResponseBody String handleCustomException(CustomGenericException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getErrCode());
        return ex.getErrMsg();
    }
}
```

And finally i have configurations in my dispatcher-servlet.xml file as below

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xyz.pqr.controller" />
```

The issue i am facing is i am getting null when below statement is executed

```
throw new CustomGenericException("E_001", "Null error");
```

Comment: Are you sure your controller advice getting called?

Comment: Based on the tutorials online that's the configuration to be made and i did exactly. That SOP is not printing means it's not getting called .. Cud you help me in fixing this.

Comment: Where did you put the advice? in what package i mean

Comment: Also, it would useful if you add your configurations and describe your project structure

Comment: I placed the Advisor in the controller package

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `handleCustomException` method and make sure it's getting called or not

Comment: And add your java/xml configs + project structure

Comment: i tried to debug, it is giving null at throw new CustomGenericException("E_001", "Null error"); statement

Comment: @Ali Dehghani, thanks for your help. i can't expose the project details. i added the code snippets exactly replicating as in the project.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution, don't use try/catch block in the methods in which you are trying to throw the custom error. And it works.